# adding documents to an existing index in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I would like to ask of how to add new documents to an existing lucene
index. in the source code below, I just change the paramater of IndexWriter into false.

```
IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(
            FSDirectory.open(indexDir),
            new SimpleAnalyzer(),
            false,
            IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);
```

because false means that the index will still be open and not close. also to add new document I should use

```
indexWriter.addDocument(doc)
```

but my question is how exactly can I add new documents to an existing lucene index. I am a bit loss in finding out where to put a new path directory containing new Documents in lucene class so that lucene can index those new documents and add it into existing indexes. any help would be appreciated though.
thanks.

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.SimpleAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class testlucene1 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File indexDir = new File("C:/Users/Raden/Documents/lucene/LuceneHibernate/adi");
    File dataDir = new File("C:/Users/Raden/Documents/lucene/LuceneHibernate/adi");
    String suffix = "txt";
    testlucene1 indexer = new testlucene1();
    int numIndex = indexer.index(indexDir, dataDir, suffix);
    System.out.println("Total files indexed " + numIndex);
}

private int index(File indexDir, File dataDir, String suffix) throws Exception {
    IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(
            FSDirectory.open(indexDir),
            new SimpleAnalyzer(),
            false,
            IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);
    indexWriter.setUseCompoundFile(false);
    indexDirectory(indexWriter, dataDir, suffix);
    int numIndexed = indexWriter.maxDoc();
    indexWriter.optimize();
    indexWriter.close();
    return numIndexed;
}

   private void indexDirectory(IndexWriter indexWriter, File dataDir, String suffix)    throws IOException {
    File[] files = dataDir.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        File f = files[i];
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            indexDirectory(indexWriter, f, suffix);
        } else {
            indexFileWithIndexWriter(indexWriter, f, suffix);
        }
    }
}

private void indexFileWithIndexWriter(IndexWriter indexWriter, File f, String suffix) throws IOException {
    if (f.isHidden() || f.isDirectory() || !f.canRead() || !f.exists()) {
        return;
    }
    if (suffix != null && !f.getName().endsWith(suffix)) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Indexing file " + f.getCanonicalPath());
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new Field("contents", new FileReader(f)));
    doc.add(new Field("filename", f.getCanonicalPath(), Field.Store.YES,  Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> also to add new document I should use
>   ....
>   but my question is how exactly can I add new documents to an existing lucene index

can you please clarify what you mean? you know how to add documents to an index, as you stated, but then you ask how to... add new documents?

Comment: allright,it was my mistake.I didn't fully understand the source code.but upon reading your comment I just realize it.thanks for the tips then. :-)

Comment: The question was how to add a new document to an existing index, not how to simply add a new document during initial indexing.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Lucene API, when you construction the `IndexWriter`, the constructor allow you specify the `IndexWriterConfig`.

```
IndexWriter(Directory d, IndexWriterConfig conf)
```

`IndexWriterConfig` allows you specify the open mode:

```
IndexWriterConfig conf = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
conf.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.APPEND);
```

And you have 3 options:

- IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.APPEND
- IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE
- IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a new `IndexWriter`, you will not create a new index (unless you explicitly tell lucene to force a new one). So your code will work, regardless of whether the index already exists.

Comment: yes I know.but I was trying to add new documents to an existing index.what do you reckon I should do to achieve this? :-)

Comment: I don't understand your question then. You create an indexwriter that looks at an existing index in the exact same way that you create an indexwriter which makes a new index. So your code will work regardless of whether `indexDir` has stuff in it or not.